# can't find a simple error when parsing with YACC

Tags: parsing, pascal, yacc, lex, parser-generator

i'm trying to make a very simple YACC parser on Pascal language which just includes integer declarations, some basic expressions and if-else statements. however, i cant find the error for hours and i'm going to be crazy soon. terminal says `Error at line:0` but it is impossible!. i use flex and byacc for parser.i will be very glad if you can help me. this is my lex file as you can see;

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
extern int yylval;
int linenum=0;
%}

digit   [0-9]
letter  [A-Za-z]

%%
if              return IF;
then                return THEN;
else                return ELSE;
for             return FOR;
while               return WHILE;
PROGRAM             return PROGRAM_SYM;
BEGIN               return BEGIN_SYM;
VAR             return VAR_SYM;
END             return END_SYM;
INTEGER             return INTEGER_SYM;
{letter}({letter}|{digit})* return identifier;
[0-9]+              return NUMBER;
[\<][\=]            return CON_LE;
[\>][\=]            return CON_GE;
[\=]                return CON_EQ;          
[\:][\=]            return ASSIGNOP;
;               return semiColon;
,               return comma;
\n              {linenum++;}
.               return (int) yytext[0];
%%
```

and this is my Yacc file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
extern FILE *yyin;
extern int linenum;
%}

%token PROGRAM_SYM VAR_SYM BEGIN_SYM END_SYM INTEGER_SYM NUMBER
%token identifier INTEGER ASSIGNOP semiColon comma THEN
%token IF ELSE FOR WHILE
%token CON_EQ CON_LE CON_GE GE LE

%left '*' '/'
%left '+' '-'

%start program

%%

program: PROGRAM_SYM identifier semiColon VAR_SYM dec_block BEGIN_SYM statement_list END_SYM '.'
     ;

dec_block:
        dec_list semiColon;

dec_list:
        dec_list dec
        |
        dec
        ;

dec: 
        int_dec_list
        ;

int_dec_list:   
        int_dec_list int_dec ':' type
        |
        int_dec ':' type
        ;

int_dec:
        int_dec comma identifier
        |
        identifier
        ;

type:
    INTEGER_SYM
    ;

statement_list:
        statement_list statement
        |
        statement
        ;

statement:
        assignment_list
        |
        expression_list
        |
        selection_list
        ;

assignment_list:
        assignment_list assignment
        |
        assignment      
        ;

assignment:

        identifier ASSIGNOP expression_list
        ;

expression_list:
        expression_list expression semiColon
        |
        expression semiColon
        ;


expression:
        '(' expression ')'
        |
        expression '*' expression
        |
        expression '/' expression
        |
        expression '+' expression
        |
        expression '-' expression
        |
        factor
        ;

factor:     
        identifier
        |
        NUMBER
        ;


selection_list:
        selection_list selection
        |
        selection
        ;

selection:
        IF '(' logical_expression ')' THEN statement_list ELSE statement_list
        ;


logical_expression:
        logical_expression '=' expression
        |
        logical_expression '>' expression
        |
        logical_expression '<' expression
        ;


%%
void yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error at line: %d\n",linenum);
}
int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Call the lexer, then quit. */
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

and finally i take an error at the first line when i give the input;

```
PROGRAM myprogram;

VAR

i:INTEGER;

i3:INTEGER;

j:INTEGER;

BEGIN

i := 3;

j := 5;

i3 := i+j*2;

i := j*20;

if(i>j)

then i3 := i+50+(45*i+(40*j));

else i3 := i+50+(45*i+(40*j))+i+50+(45*i+(30*j));

END.
```

Comment: Which version of Yacc are you using?  When I compile your code with `bison`, I get warnings about `grammar.y: warning: 3 useless nonterminals and 7 useless rules` and `grammar.y: conflicts: 8 shift/reduce` (and specific error messages in between).  Are you planning to fix any of those before running the program?  (FWIW: when I do run the program despite the warnings, I get the same error message you do.)

Comment: it should be `byacc` and even i get 13 shift/reduce conflicts they shouldnt be a problem cause as i said it consists of very simple grammar and by the way it says `Error at line 0`. i even try to write the tree form but couldnt realize the problem

Comment: it is so stupid that it gives the error at line 0!! i'm trying to solve this for hours but no improvement...

Comment: Note that the example posted is NOT valid Pascal. In this context a ";" before the else is not allowed, so if it is parsed as correct, the parser is wrong. This is part of Pascal's solution/hack to the dangling else problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lexical analyzer returns blanks and tabs as tokens, but the grammar doesn't recognize them.

Add a parser rule:

```
[ \t\r]    { }
```

This gets you to line 6 instead of line 0 before you run into an error.  You get that error because you don't allow semicolons between declarations:

```
dec_block:
        dec_list semiColon;

dec_list:
        dec_list dec
        |
        dec
        ;

dec:
        int_dec_list
        ;
```

That should probably be:

```
dec_block:
        dec_block dec
        |
        dec
        ;

dec:
        int_dec_list semiColon
        ;
```

Doing this gets you to line 14 in the input.

Incidentally, one of the first things I did was to ensure that the lexical analyzer tells me what it is doing, by modifying the rules like this:

```
if              { printf("IF\n"); return IF; }
```

In long term code, I'd make that diagnostic output selectable at run-time.

---

You have a general problem with where you expect semicolons.  It is also not clear that you should allow an `expression_list` in the rule for `statement` (or, maybe, 'not yet' — that might be appropriate when you have function calls, but allowing `3 + 2 / 4` as a 'statement' is not very helpful).

---

This grammar gets to the end of the input:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
extern FILE *yyin;
extern int linenum;
%}

%token PROGRAM_SYM VAR_SYM BEGIN_SYM END_SYM INTEGER_SYM NUMBER
%token identifier INTEGER ASSIGNOP semiColon comma THEN
%token IF ELSE FOR WHILE
%token CON_EQ CON_LE CON_GE GE LE

%left '*' '/'
%left '+' '-'

%start program

%%

program: PROGRAM_SYM identifier semiColon VAR_SYM dec_block BEGIN_SYM statement_list END_SYM '.'
     ;

dec_block:
        dec_block dec
        |
        dec
        ;

dec:
        int_dec_list semiColon
        ;

int_dec_list:
        int_dec_list int_dec ':' type
        |
        int_dec ':' type
        ;

int_dec:
        int_dec comma identifier
        |
        identifier
        ;

type:
    INTEGER_SYM
    ;

statement_list:
        statement_list statement
        |
        statement
        ;

statement:
        assignment
        |
        selection
        ;

assignment:
        identifier ASSIGNOP expression semiColon
        ;

expression:
        '(' expression ')'
        |
        expression '*' expression
        |
        expression '/' expression
        |
        expression '+' expression
        |
        expression '-' expression
        |
        factor
        ;

factor:
        identifier
        |
        NUMBER
        ;

selection:
        IF '(' logical_expression ')' THEN statement_list ELSE statement_list
        ;

logical_expression:
        expression '=' expression
        |
        expression '>' expression
        |
        expression '<' expression
        ;

%%
void yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error at line: %d\n",linenum);
}
int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Call the lexer, then quit. */
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

Key changes include removing `assignment_list` and `expression_list`, and modifying `logical_expression` so that the two sides of the expansion are `expression`, rather than the LHS being `logical_expression` (which then never had a primitive definition, leading to the problems with warnings).

There are still issues to resolve; the `expression_list` in the `selection` should be more restrictive to accurately reflect the grammar of Pascal.  (You need a block where that could be a single statement or a BEGIN, statement list, END.)

Comment: yeah with this code its more satisfying but are you sure that it shows at 6_? cause it show at 3 on my terminal_?

Comment: ok now it shows at 7 and i'm going to add these printf functions. you are rigth this way will be more helpful

Comment: well as i said i'm just started at a simple example. so this code will change by time(for example if i try to parse the function calls). and also i tried that meaningless statements to check if it give an error not. but compiler continued to compile even without warnings. thats why i let simple calculations as a statement

Comment: finally i solved the problem. it is about only semiColons which i put them at wrong places to parse and i realized that in logical_expression it couldnt come to a non-terminal i just add expression to end of it. and used printf functions to see what tokens are coming as parameters to YACC. so thanks Jonathan caring a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For debugging grammars, YYDEBUG is your friend.  Either stick `#define YYDEBUG 1` in the `%{`..`%}` in the top of your .y file, or compile with `-DYYDEBUG`, and stick a `yydebug = 1;` in `main` before calling `yyparse` and you'll get a slew of info about what tokens the parser is seeing and what it is doing with them....

Comment: yeah this works very well another way to realize what your parser do! thanks a lot